# Вертикальная прокрутка

Tags: javascript

Если сайт прокручен до самого низа, появляется какой-нить блок с информацией. 
Как это проще всего реализовать?

Comment: js/jQuery. У вас есть граница какого-то блока в самом низу. При скролле проверяете насколько страница прокручена и, когда значения совпадут или больше, чем граница того самого блока, показываете блок с информацией или что вы там задумали.

Comment: как проверять? ) вот в чем вопрос ))

Answer (score 1):

Используя jQuery: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/my5RB/)

Comment: 1. К чему метка в начале? В каком году такое использовали последний раз?

2. Переменные можно обьявлять подряд через запятую, а не по отдельности.

3. В `javascript` переменные могут начинаться с любого символа, а не только с `$`, как в `php`.

Comment: 1. Без понятия, пока вы не написали, я ее и не видел, естественно, не писал
2. Вкурсе, но писался код для демонстрации, а так читать удобней
3. Вкурсе, как называть переменные - лично мое дело, мне так удобней

Comment: @Crasher dekameron правильно использовал $, т.к. существует метаправило, при использовании jQuery объекты jQuery называть $object, чтобы отличать их от других. например:

    vat $output=$('#output'),output=$output.get(0);